# Is it possible to show notification every minute with date and time content in the notification inside flutter app using native code or inside flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, background

I am trying to build the app where I want to show notification every minute in flutter but I didn't get fine solution now I am trying to do with native android code using android foreground service I've created the service but I am not able to update it every minute so, the question is How can I do the task.

I am trying to show notification with date time in it's content in flutter app with flutter_background_service but it stops after some time so i decide to implement this with native android kotlin code and i have created the service class and it works fine now i am not able to update the notification every minute so the question is how can i do the task